# Tensorflow streaming metrics are not working

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to implement the algorithm here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.02098.pdf

For some reason I always get 0.2 recall and 0 accuracy. Am I using the streaming metrics correctly? The documentation only has a pseudo code. Here is my code:

---

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from nltk.corpus import brown
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
from tensorflow.contrib.metrics import streaming_accuracy, streaming_recall

data = brown.tagged_sents()

tags = set()
for sent in data:
    for token, tag in sent:
        tags.add(tag)

label_processor = LabelBinarizer()
label_processor.fit(list(tags))

embedding_dim = 100
word2vec = Word2Vec(brown.sents(), size=embedding_dim, min_count=1)
embedding = word2vec.wv
del word2vec # Saves RAM

test = 0.1
val = 0.1

data_length = len(data)
inds = np.random.permutation(np.arange(data_length))

test_inds = inds[:int(data_length*test)]
val_inds = inds[int(data_length*test):int(data_length*(val+test))]
train_inds = inds[int(data_length*(val+test)):]

val_x = []
val_y = []
for i in val_inds:
    x = []
    tags = []

    for token, tag in data[i]:
        x.append(embedding[token])
        tags.append(tag)

    x = np.array(x)
    x = x.reshape(x.shape[0], 1, x.shape[1], 1)
    y = np.array(label_processor.transform(tags))

    val_x.append(x)
    val_y.append(y)

val_x = np.concatenate(val_x, axis=0)
val_y = np.concatenate(val_y, axis=0)

test_x = []
test_y = []
for i in test_inds:
    x = []
    tags = []

    for token, tag in data[i]:
        x.append(embedding[token])
        tags.append(tag)

    x = np.array(x)
    x = x.reshape(x.shape[0], 1, x.shape[1], 1)
    y = np.array(label_processor.transform(tags))

    test_x.append(x)
    test_y.append(y)

test_x = np.concatenate(test_x, axis=0)
test_y = np.concatenate(test_y, axis=0)

learning_rate = 0.001
n_iter = 12000
display_step = 100
depth = 5

label_processor
n_classes = label_processor.classes_.shape[0]
dropout_prob = 0.50

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1, embedding_dim, 1])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_classes])
dropout = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [])
depth_tensor = tf.constant(depth, tf.float32)

def data_processor(data, train_inds, word2vec, label_processor, n_iter):    
    inds = np.random.randint(len(train_inds), size=(n_iter))

    for i in inds:                
        x = []
        tags = []

        for token, tag in data[train_inds[i]]:
            x.append(word2vec[token])
            tags.append(tag)

        x = np.array(x)
        x = x.reshape(x.shape[0], 1, x.shape[1], 1)
        y = np.array(label_processor.transform(tags))

        yield x, y 

def model(x, y, weights, biases, dropout, depth_tensor):
    net = tf.nn.dropout(x, dropout)
    net = tf.nn.conv2d(net, weights['first'], strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
    net = tf.nn.bias_add(net, biases['first']) 
    net = tf.nn.relu(net)

    net_flat = tf.reshape(net, [-1, weights['out'].get_shape().as_list()[0]])
    preds = tf.add(tf.matmul(net_flat, weights['out']), biases['out'])
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=preds, labels=y))
    for i in range(1, depth): 
        net = tf.nn.dropout(net, dropout)
        net = tf.nn.atrous_conv2d(net, weights['iterated'], rate=2**i, padding='SAME')
        net = tf.nn.bias_add(net, biases['iterated'])
        net = tf.nn.relu(net)

        net_flat = tf.reshape(net, [-1, weights['out'].get_shape().as_list()[0]])
        preds = tf.add(tf.matmul(net_flat, weights['out']), biases['out'])
        cost += tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=preds, labels=y))

    return preds, tf.divide(cost, depth_tensor)  

weights = {'first': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1, 3, 1, 10])),
           'iterated': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1, 3, 10, 10])),
           'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([embedding_dim*10, n_classes]))}

biases = {'first': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([10])),
          'iterated': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([10])),
          'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))}

preds, cost = model(x, y, weights, biases, dropout, depth_tensor)

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)

accuracy, update_accuracy = streaming_accuracy(y, preds)
recall, update_recall = streaming_recall(y, preds)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
init2 = tf.local_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    i = 1

    for batch_x, batch_y in data_processor(data, train_inds, embedding, label_processor, n_iter):
        sess.run(optimizer, 
                 feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y, 
                            dropout: dropout_prob})

        if i % display_step == 0:
            loss = sess.run(cost, 
                            feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y, dropout: dropout_prob})

            print("Iter:{}, Minibatch Loss:{:.6f}".format(i,loss))
        i += 1

    sess.run(init2)
    for batch_x, batch_y in data_processor(data, val_inds, embedding, label_processor, n_iter):
        recall, accuracy = sess.run([update_recall, update_accuracy], 
                                    feed_dict={x:batch_x, y: batch_y, dropout: 1})

        f1 = 2 * recall * accuracy / (recall + accuracy)

    print("Testing Accuracy:", accuracy,"Testing Recall:", recall, "Testing F1 Score:", f1)
```

And here is the part where I used the streaming metrics:

```
accuracy, update_accuracy = streaming_accuracy(y, preds)
recall, update_recall = streaming_recall(y, preds)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
init2 = tf.local_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    i = 1

    for batch_x, batch_y in data_processor(data, train_inds, embedding, label_processor, n_iter):
        sess.run(optimizer, 
                 feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y, 
                            dropout: dropout_prob})

        if i % display_step == 0:
            loss = sess.run(cost, 
                            feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y, dropout: dropout_prob})

            print("Iter:{}, Minibatch Loss:{:.6f}".format(i,loss))
        i += 1

    sess.run(init2)
    for batch_x, batch_y in data_processor(data, val_inds, embedding, label_processor, n_iter):
        recall, accuracy = sess.run([update_recall, update_accuracy], 
                                    feed_dict={x:batch_x, y: batch_y, dropout: 1})

        f1 = 2 * recall * accuracy / (recall + accuracy)
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's hard to tell exactly what's going wrong with a long section of code like this. Do you have a smaller reproducible case you can share?

Comment: I separated the part where I used the streaming metrics. Is is fine like this?

Answer (score 1):

While, I believe it's because you have only run `update op` but `fetch op`.

The codes below:

```
for batch_x, batch_y in data_processor(data, val_inds, embedding, label_processor, n_iter):
    recall, accuracy = sess.run([update_recall, update_accuracy], 
                                feed_dict={x:batch_x, y: batch_y, dropout: 1})
    f1 = 2 * recall * accuracy / (recall + accuracy)
```

Should be:

```
for batch_x, batch_y in data_processor(data, val_inds, embedding, label_processor, n_iter):
    _, recall_value, _, accuracy_value = sess.run([update_recall, recall, update_accuracy, accuracy], 
                                feed_dict={x:batch_x, y: batch_y, dropout: 1})
    f1 = 2 * recall_value * accuracy_value / (recall_value + accuracy_value)
```

The tensor `accuracy` and `recall` holds the actual value and the `update*` are just used to update the internal counter variables to calculate the final metric value.

By the way: I've not tested the codes. Please let me know if it doesn't work as you expected.